# Continuous Integration System for Delphi

Tags: delphi, continuous-integration

Are there any CI-Systems for Delphi like Hudson for Java?
Does Hudson has any Delphi integrations?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We use Hudson :), which works just fine with Delphi.

Here's a complete setup for one of my projects:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.CVSSCM">
    <cvsroot>:sspi:cvsonly:foo@bar:/baz</cvsroot>
    <module>SIP</module>
    <canUseUpdate>false</canUseUpdate>
    <flatten>true</flatten>
    <isTag>false</isTag>
    <excludedRegions></excludedRegions>
  </scm>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <triggers class="vector"/>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.BatchFile>
      <command>&quot;C:\Program Files\Nant\bin\nant&quot; -buildfile:etc\sip.build build-d7 test</command>
    </hudson.tasks.BatchFile>
  </builders>
  <publishers>
    <hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger>
      <childProjects>quux, foozle, wibble</childProjects>
      <threshold>
        <name>SUCCESS</name>
        <ordinal>0</ordinal>
        <color>BLUE</color>
      </threshold>
    </hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger>
  </publishers>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

sip.build's delphi-7 target builds the project's test suite (DUnit's TextTestRunner) and so the output of the job is simply the count of failed/error tests thanks to:

```
var
  R: TTestResult;

begin
  R := TextTestRunner.RunRegisteredTests;
  ExitCode := R.ErrorCount + R.FailureCount;
end;
```

Comment: +1 for Hudson - you might get more if you explain how, of course :-)

Comment: +1 for Hudson
We use hudson + pasdoc + DUnit + InnoSetup + SourceMonitor

Comment: I am familar with hudson so I give it a try.
The combination hudson + pasdoc + DUnit + InnoSetup + SourceMonitor sounds great @Daniele

Comment: @DanieleTeti: Maybe you should answer the question about how to integrate SourceMonitor to Hudson: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649205/integrating-sourcemonitor-into-a-jenkins-ci-system

Comment: @Frank Shearar What do you do with the test results? Do you use a plugin? Can you elaborate more about how you got the DUnit working with Jenkins?

Comment: It's been 5 years now since I did this work, but when I wrote this up, DUnit produced a JUnit-compatible test result file, which Jenkins understands (possibly through a standard plugin).

Answer (score 17):

[FinalBuilder Server](http://www.finalbuilder.com/finalbuilder-server.aspx)

now replaced with :
[Continua CI](https://www.finalbuilder.com/continua-ci)

Comment: We use this without any problems.   FinalBuilder is always up to date with the latest Delphi versions.  (It's written partially in Delphi)

Comment: https://www.finalbuilder.com/continua-ci  from the site: "FinalBuilder Server is not recommended for new installations.
Continua CI has replaced FinalBuilder Server for all your continuous integration needs."

Answer (score 8):

We use [CruiseControl.NET](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org), which works perfectly with Delphi.

Answer (score 6):

It seems Embarcadero itself uses Hudson. See the comment from Nick Hodges, Development Manager at Embarcadero. http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nickhodges/2010/03/10/39369#comment-29952

Comment: They use both Hudson, and Cruisecontrol, depending on the team, the product, and the language of implementation. Mostly hudson.

Answer (score 6):

**[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)** is great, it is also available as [MSI setup](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2010/01/26/msi-installers-hudson). Users of older Delphi versions (pre MSBuild), can create build scripts with the popular Apache Ant and NAnt build script environments. Simple command line (batch script) builds are possible too of course.

> One of the highlights of this
>   installer is that it comes with a JRE,
>   to be fully self-contained. This is
>   because Windows users don't normally
>   know what to do with the *.war file,
>   and they generally don't like going to
>   the command prompt and running Java
>   command manually.

So it is easy to try without going through too many installers and command lines first.

And after installation make sure to visit the plug in page in the administration app, there are many extensions available which are also useful for Delphi developers. A plugin overview is online [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins).

Hudson tools for Delphi: there is also a [Code Coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) tool for Delphi with Hudson support [here](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-code-coverage/).

**[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)** is another very nice CI system. It is a commercial product, but offers a free license for up to 20 users and 20 build configurations on 3 build agents.

**[Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/)** is a CI system for any language. It is available from Atlassian. Its price starts at $10 - this includes all features and unlimited users, but limited to 10 plans, running builds only on the server where it is installed. It can use Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud instances as remote agents.

**[Automated Build Studio](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/abs/)** from SmartBear. With Automated Build Studio Server, it introduced CI some time before FinalBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

We use [jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/).
Jenkins has a [RAD Studio plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bds-plugin/) to integrate the compilation of Delphi projects into jobs. It's not mandatory to use it (plugin), we use command-line tools and MSBuild to compile the projects.

The [project DUnItX](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/DUnitX_Overview) (to create unit testing) integrates seamlessly with Jenkins.

Here you can find some articles about the integration of Jenkins and Delphi. Introduction, installation,... Are in Spanish but you can translate without problems and with included images and code are quite simple.

[1- Integración continua con Delphi (GIT)](https://neftali.clubdelphi.com/1-integracion-continua-con-delphi-git/)  (INTRODUCTION)
[2- Integración continua con Delphi (Jenkins) – Instalación](https://neftali.clubdelphi.com/2-integracin-continua-con-delphi-jenkins-instalacin/)  (INSTALLATION)
[3- Integración continua con Delphi (Jenkins) – Primer proyecto](https://neftali.clubdelphi.com/3-integracin-continua-con-delphi-jenkins-primer-proyecto/) (FIRST PROJECT)
[4- Integración continua con Delphi (Jenkins) – Pipelines](https://neftali.clubdelphi.com/4-integracin-continua-con-delphi-jenkins-pipelines/) (USE OF PIPELINES)

Answer (score 1):

Add our [**Parabuild**](http://www.viewtier.com/products/parabuild/index.htm) to the list of tools to check out - it builds practically **anything** that can be built from the command line - that includes Delphi, and it provides integration with Perforce and other version control systems such as Git and Bazaar.

Answer (score 0):

**Hudson** is simple to use, with some web-based assistants, as Delphi projects are  built with MSBuild.

If you need more customization and 3rd party tools integration (integrate metrics tools for example) then **CruiseControl.NET** is the ideal solution.

Have a look to my [CC.NET Dashboard page for DelphiCodeToDoc](http://trident.job.hd.free.fr/cc_net) (and you can have a look to the configuration file also). I'm doing **checkout + compilation of gui and command line version and unit test + unit test execution and report + ftp upload build delivery**.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw my support for CruiseControl.NET, as Delphi 2007 and above are based around MSBuild, then there should be no problem with builds via CC.NET. There is a patch somewhere for DUNit, so that it outputs the results to an XML file, and this can then be integrated into the builds results charts.

Answer (score 0):

errrm, can you define what you are actually looking for?

You use the phrase `continuous integration`, but do you just mean `continuous build` to make sure it compiles and likes, or do you actually mean `continuous integration` in the sense that you also run regression tests?

I would be curios as to how you do that (Auto-it?).

Not that it really matters too much, because the wonderful Hudson (which is decidedly *not* just for java) has numerous plug-ins, but will also allow you to execute a DOS batch script - any script that you care to write, to build, to test, to report results, etc.

Comment: regression test would be great but I am not soure how to do them. 
I knew that Hudson is very flexibel but I really don't want to write custom batch scripts. A out of the box solution would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (although not free, $10 for limited # of users) is [Atlassian Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/). And JetBrains TeamCity is another that is free (with limited # of users). I've tried both with Delphi 2009/2010, and they work quite well. Both allowed integration with Perforce among other SCM's.

Answer (score 0):

We use Jenkins CI system with [Owly CI](http://owlyci.com) tool as the build system and dependency handler.

Take a look on this [tutorial](http://owlyci.com/docs/tutorial/jenkins)

Initial setup takes less than 5 minutes