# Integrating SourceMonitor into a Jenkins CI-System

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I would like to integrate SourceMonitor into my Jenkins CI-system. Since there is no SourceMonitor plugin how can i make the results of SourceMonitor visible on my Jenkins Server.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue associated with the Violations plugin.

You can vote up for the implementation of this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5741

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're out of luck. You could take a look at similar plugins (probably FindBugs, PMD, Checkstyle plugins should be comparable) and write a plugin yourself.

You could also give a try to post to the Jenkins user mailing list, maybe someone there can help you.

Don't know what kind of output SourceMonitor produces, but if it produces HTML Reports, there is an HTML Publish Plugin, which would let you link and display those results in your job. Not as integrated as a real plugin would be, but perhaps that would be enough for you.

Answer (score -1):

You only realistically have the following options:

1. Create a Hudson plugin for SourceMonitor yourself.
2. Contact the SourceMonitor development team and ask them to create a Hudson plugin.
3. Use an existing Hudson plugin that is similar to SourceMonitor.

Comment: I prefer Option number 3. I hoped that someone is using SourceMonitor in Hudson, and knows a plugin that is similar so it can be used for the integration